# Unity エディタがダークスキンになりません

Tags: unity3d

Unity Proを購入したのですがエディタの色がダークスキンに変更されません、
Help＞manager licenseをみるとProライセンス認識はされています。

なにか設定が必要なのでしょうか。

Comment: 設定変更の操作をしたけれど変わらなかったということでしょうか？ [How can I use light theme instead of dark theme on Unity3D Pro?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1132847/how-can-i-use-light-theme-instead-of-dark-theme-on.html), [How Can I Change My Editor Theme?](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004982743-How-can-I-change-my-Editor-theme-), [Unity User Manual (2019.3)Working in UnityEditor FeaturesPreferences](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preferences.html)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます、ライセンスを再度入れ直したら解決いたしました。

Answer (score 2):

Unityアカウント＞シートから対象のアクティベートを削除、
削除後ライセンスを再度入れ直したら無事解決いたしました。